# How to scan an image in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin. Forms application where it needs to scan an image. I am trying to find any open source for it but unable to find it. Can anybody please help me to find any open source for it, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "scan an image"?  Taking a picture with the camera?  Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Jason. I meant to increase the quality of an image even with lower dpi my actual case is to scan the captured cheque image.

Comment: do you mean OCR - Optical Character Recognition?

Comment: Yes, @Jason. exactly

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+ocr+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Jason.Sorry, but I think there is some misunderstanding from my end. What I meant by scan was like this; https://scanbot.io/products/xamarin-forms-document-scanner-sdk. I am looking to implement such scanning functionality for captured images from my app.

Comment: then you really should have specified that in your question.  Why don't you just use Scanbot?

Comment: That Scanbot is paid thing and I am looking for open sources.

Comment: Yes, and I gave you a link to a number of other potential solutions, some of which are open source.  Further, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow "